# What's a good free PostScript viewer for Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7

I tried Ghostscript and GSView but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate what kind of problems you found with Ghostscript and GSView, or what they were lacking that you needed?

Comment: You didn't install a 32-bit gsview with a 64-bit ghostscript, did you? (or vice versa) Also, did you try the 4.91 beta available from the developer's page? ( http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/) It has Windows 7 specific fixes.

Comment: Duplicate of [A better PostScript reader than GhostView](http://superuser.com/questions/89952).

Answer (score 1):

[IrfranView](http://www.irfanview.com/) can display PostScript files on a Windows 7 system, but like many free image viewers it too uses GhostScript.

Comment: And it only shows the first page.